# How to read the length of audio files using Juce "C++." Without playing the file

Tags: c++, audio, playlist, juce

I'm trying to display the length of audio files in a Playlist component for an application.
I've not used Juce or C++ before, and I can't understand how to do that from Juce documentation.
I want to make a function that takes an audio file's URL and returns the length in seconds of that audio without playing that file or doing anything else with that file.
I've tried a lot of things, and all of them didn't work, and this is the last thing I've tried:

```
void PlaylistComponent::trackStats(URL audioURL)
{
    AudioFormatManager formatManager;
    std::unique_ptr<AudioFormatReaderSource> readerSource;
    AudioTransportSource transportSource;

    auto* reader = formatManager.createReaderFor(audioURL.createInputStream(false));
    if (reader != nullptr) 
    {
        std::unique_ptr<AudioFormatReaderSource> newSource(new AudioFormatReaderSource(reader, true));
        transportSource.setSource(newSource.get(), 0, nullptr, reader->sampleRate);
        readerSource.reset(newSource.release());

        DBG("PlaylistComponent::trackStats(URL audioURL): " << transportSource.getLengthInSeconds());
    }
    else
    {
        DBG("Something went wrong loading the file");
    }
}
```

And this is the PlaylistComponent header file:

```
class PlaylistComponent  : public juce::Component, 
                           public juce::TableListBoxModel,
                           public Button::Listener,
                           public FileDragAndDropTarget
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

juce::AudioFormatReaderSource has a method called `getTotalLength()` which returns the total amount of samples.
Divide that by the sample rate of the file and you have the total length in seconds. Something like this:

```
if (auto* reader = audioFormatReaderSource->getAudioFormatReader())
    double lengthInSeconds = static_cast<double> (audioFormatReaderSource->getTotalLength()) / reader->sampleRate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very early on in the audio file opening procedure. You only need an AudioFormatReader instance (no need to create an AudioFormatReaderSource):

```
    // create juce::File from a path juce::String (from a drag & drop event etc).
    File file{filePath};
    // make sure it is a file and not a directory, etc.
    if (!file.existsAsFile()) return;

    // create the AudioFormatReader that contains the data
    AudioFormatReader *reader = formatManagerInstance.createReaderFor(file);
    // make sure a valid reader can be created (not an unsupported file)
    if (reader == nullptr) return;

    // log the length in seconds
    std::cout << reader->lengthInSamples / reader->sampleRate << "\n";
```

Note: for this to work you will need to

1. have access to your AudioFormatManager instance and
2. have already registered the format(s) of the file type (usually through a *.registerBasicFormats()* call on your AudioFormatManager instance.

IMPORTANT: if successful the createReaderFor() method uses **new** to create a new AudioFormatReaderInstance, so make sure to use **delete** on it when you are finished using it to avoid memory leaks